# create django user based on existing model object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm working on Property Management django app where my base model is **Tenant** with all basic info like name, surname, email etc. Willing tenants will be able to create **user account** so they can log in and book Gym/Cinema, but not all Tenants will need to have user account. My problem is:

How can I **create new user accounts** based on **existing** Tenant objects? Obviously user will have Tenant ForeignKey but how can I extract Tenant.name, Tenant.surname etc to more than 1 field in my user model?

ForeignKey only gives me reference to object but can I somehow access certain fields of that object during creation of new user so I make sure that Tenant.email is the same as user.email?

**Edit**

```
tenancy = (('Tenant', 'Tenant'),('Owner', 'Owner'), ('Other', 'Other'))

class Tenant(models.Model):

    name          = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=False)
    surname       = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    email         = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    phone_number  = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    flat          = models.ForeignKey(Flat, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    status        = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=tenancy, null=True, blank=False)
    stay_length   = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=False)
    pet_licence   = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=False)
    additional_notes= models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    date_added    = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    moved_out     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_moved_out= models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'surname',)


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {self.surname}'
```

Now I'd like to create user account model where name, surname, email, phone_number and flat will be ForeignKeys of Tenant model. Is it even possible to have 4 ForeignKeys from 1 object populating new model?

I've tried playing around with ForeignKey.limit_choices_to, ForeignKey.related_name, ForeignKey.to_field (this was close but field related to has to be unique which doesn't work for my case) but everything gives errors. I just want to find out if it's even possible that more than 1 ForeignKey of 1 object can be directed to multiple different fields of new model object.

Comment: what is tenent?

Comment: Can you show your models, and what you have attempted so far to solve this?

Comment: JoranBeasley Tenant is someone who rents a flat, an apartment or any other place to live at. @bdbd I answered in edit, have a look if you'll have a chance. Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered a [one-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) relation with user model that can be null?

Comment: @bdbd I can't have user with null- every user has to be assigned to exactly 1 tenant with the same fields, not every tenant has to become user though. 1to1 with null=True doesn't solve the problem of how to use more fields of Tenant and assign them to more fields of user unfortunately.

Comment: No I meant the foreign key to user from tenant can be null. So some tenant can have user, while some don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it in a way that the foreign key is in `Tenant`, instead of `User`, and define it as a nullable [`one-to-one`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/). This way you keep your `User` model free of foreign keys:

```py
class Tenant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        related_name='tenant',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        default=None,
    )
```

Then to create the related user, you can add a method in your `Tenant` model like so:

```py
class Tenant(models.Model):
    ...
    def create_user(self):
        if not self.user:
            user = User.objects.create(
                first_name=self.name,
                last_name=self.surname,
                ...
            )
            self.user = user
            self.save()
```

Have a look at the example from the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Comment: Yes! I've just tried it and it does the job well, thanks. It achieves my main goals- I have full control over all User fields and I make sure that they are the same as Tenant in the back-end rather than front-end (so they can't be messed up by admins). User model doesn't interfere with Tenant and can be used only when needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_field` to create fkeys to non-pk fields of another model, however, those fields need to have a unique constraint (i.e. `unique=True`) - which seems unlikely for name/surname.

It sounds like you want a transparent access from the User model to the Tenant models fields, and that is not possible.

You can create a fkey from User to Tenant:

```
class User(models.Model):
    tenant = models.OneToOneField(Tenant, null=True, blank=True, related_name='user')
    ...
```

and then access the fields with

```
user = User.objects.get(...)
user.tenant.surname
```

to keep the fields in sync you can override the `save()` method:

```
class Tenant(...)
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.user:
             self.user.last_name = self.surname
             ...
             self.user.save()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

aside: `null=True` indicates that the database should allow null in the field, `blank=True` says that the field can be empty in the admin interface. You should probably have `null=True, blank=True` in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. Could you please explain in simple terms what exactly def save() would do in class Tenant and at what point I would use it? Appreciated!

Comment: save() will be called whenever a Tenant object is saved, and it should copy any update information to the corresponding User fields.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will be trialing this solution. I wanted to keep everything foolproof so even admins can't mess it up that's why automatic import would be easier solution (if existed!) but I will try to handle all that in views and front end. Thanks for help!

Comment: The save() function will be called in almost all cases where a model is changed, including from the admin, i.e. if someone changes Tenant data in admin, the save() function will make sure the User object gets updated automagically.

Comment: Good suggestion! I implemented it, thanks, always will keep things more tidy.